# Cancellation of an indefinite leave to remain when divorcing

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, divorce

I am an Indian citizen, having UK ILR and want to know if ILR will be cancelled if I do not visit UK for 2 years?

Actually I'm getting separated from my husband who is a British national and want to cancel my ILR now which is a precursor to our divorce.

Please advise how will it be revoked?

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: Do you want to cancel it? Or does he want to and you are asking how you can avoid that?

Comment: You do not need to cancel your ILR to get a divorce. But you may need to notify the Home Office of the divorce.

Answer (score 2):

The ILR should not be affected in this case by your matrimonial status however it is intended for people settling in the country. In effect the ILR does lapse after 2 years of living abroad however there may be exceptions depending on individual circumstances.

I would advise to contact you [citizen advice bureau](http://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/) for free legal advice if your are still in the UK or the nearest British embassy/consulate for clarifications.